# Type erasure and collections

Tags: java, generics, type-safety

I am having a specific problem implementing a parametrised class Parameter, but this is something I have come across before with generics, so a general solution would be good..

The class Parameter stores a value of one of a strict number of classes:

```
public class Parameter<T> {

/*
 * Specify what types of parameter are valid
 */
private static final Set<Class<?>> VALID_TYPES;
static {
    Set<Class<?>> set = new HashSet<Class<?>>();

    set.add( Integer.class );
    set.add( Float.class );
    set.add( Boolean.class );
    set.add( String.class );

    VALID_TYPES = Collections.unmodifiableSet(set);
}

private T value;

public Parameter(T initialValue) throws IllegalArgumentException {

    // Parameter validity check
    if (!VALID_TYPES.contains(initialValue.getClass())) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                initialValue.getClass() + " is not a valid parameter type");
    }

    value = initialValue;
}

    public T get() { return value; }

    public void set(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

This is all fine, until I try and store instances of Parameter in a collection. For example:

```
Parameter<Integer> p = new Parameter<Integer>(3); 
int value = (Integer)p.get();
p.set(2); // Fine

ArrayList<Parameter<?>> ps = new ArrayList<Parameter<?>>();
ps.add(p);
value = (Integer)(ps.get(0).get());

ps.get(0).set(4); // Does not compile due to type erasure
```

What would others do in this situation to get round this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can't directly work around this.. But perhaps you could remember the class of the initial value?

```
class Parameter<T> {
    // ...
    private T value;
    private final Class<?> klass;

    public Parameter(T initialValue) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if (!VALID_TYPES.contains(initialValue.getClass()))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(...);
        value = initialValue;
        klass = initialValue.getClass();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void set(Object value) {
        if (value != null && value.getClass() != klass)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(...);
        this.value = (T)value;
    }
```

However, you will lose compile-time type checks on set()..

Answer (score 0):

<strike>It's not type erasure - you try to assign an integer value to an object type variable. This only *works* if the parameter type is `Integer`, then the compiler knows that the integer has to be inboxed.</strike>

Try this instead:

<strike>ps.get(0).set(new Integer(4));</strike>

*What* you can do right away: remove the `<?>` expression entirely. It will *replace* the compiler error by a compiler warning. Not brilliant at all but compiles.

Comment: actually, the type is not Object, but <capture-of ?> .. anyhow, at least in my compiler, new Integer(..) also doesn't work..

Comment: yes, same here: The method set(capture#2-of ?) in the type Parameter<capture#2-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (Integer)

Comment: yeah, I see. Don't have clue yet, *why* it doesn't work. Does even complain when I use `<? extends Object>` instead...